# VBA - Using Excel Variable in Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, macros

I am trying to use a variable defined in Excel in Word. I am using two separate macros, but all the code is written in Excel. I am trying to control Word from Excel.

Here is the code I have in my Excel Macro:

```
Public DJ, Pick, Customer, Line, Model As Variant
Public LineOne, LineThr As Integer
Dim OP As String
Dim LastRow As Long

'Dims variables for pick stickers
Public Subinv, Loc, PN, Req, Desc As String

Public Sub Picklist()
```

In this Sub, it goes on to define the DJ variable as a random set of 8 number (i.e. 94673920), it changes every time. Then I'm trying to pass that variable of in Word under a different sub. Here is the code for that:

```
Public Sub PickLabel()

Dim WordApp, WordDoc As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Opens up the Pick Stickers Generator in Word
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
        WordApp.Visible = True
Dim WordSel
    Set WordSel = WordApp.Selection
    
With WordSel
    .Font.Size = 60
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .TypeText ("DJ: " & DJ)
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignCenter
End With
```

End Sub

It's not inserting the DJ variable like how I want it to. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your code with the following:

```
PickLabel(DJ)

Public Sub PickLabel(vRandom as long)

Dim WordApp, WordDoc As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Opens up the Pick Stickers Generator in Word
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
        WordApp.Visible = True
Dim WordSel
    Set WordSel = WordApp.Selection
    
With WordSel
    .Font.Size = 60
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .TypeText ("DJ: " & vRandom)
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignCenter
End With
```